# Detect Rspec test failure on after each method

Tags: ruby, methods, rspec

I am trying to run an RSpec test, and I want to detect if the test failed in the `after` method. I have something like this right now:

```
after(:each) do
  cc = ConnectController.new()
  cc.update(<TEST-SERVER-CONTROLLER>, <TC-RESULT-ID>, result?)    
end
```

As you can see, the `result?` function is what I need to replace, to detect if the test fails or not, and to also get information about the test that failed.

Answer (score 25):

In addition to Daniel's answer, in Rspec3 the example method was deleted (see [here](http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2013/07/the-plan-for-rspec-3) for more info).

You will have to do something like this:

```
after(:each) do |example|
  if example.exception
    # ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 15):

EDIT: this answer is only valid for RSpec 2. for RSpec 3 see geekazoid's answer.

The after each block runs in the context of class which exposes `example` and you can detect failures by checking the `exception` method on `example` thusly:

```
after(:each) do
  if example.exception != nil
    # Failure only code goes here
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for how to check if success for all examples in a group in a `after(:context)` / `after(:all)` block. Here's what I came up with:

```
after(:all) do |example_group|
  all_groups = example_group.class.descendants
  failed_examples = all_groups.map(&:examples).flatten.select(&:exception)

  if failed_examples.empty?
    # runs only if there are no failures
    do('something')
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. All the other answers were focused on `after(:each)` which adds to the runtime. It's really useful to be able to check once after the whole suite.